# Отменить git reset --hard

Tags: git

Случайно сделал git reset --hard, при этом не закоммитив текущие изменения (то, что написал после последнего коммита). 
Соответственно, все файлы откатились к последнему коммиту (как я понял).
Подскажите, можно ли вернуться к тем самым файлам до git reset --hard?

Comment: Один из вариантов: [How To: Recover From a Git Hard Reset](https://medium.com/@CarrieGuss/how-to-recover-from-a-git-hard-reset-b830b5e3f60c), начиная со слов "To recover your files, you’re going to be using “git fsck”" Но нужно понимать, что никакой гарантии нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, там бред какой-то написан. автору: ваш вопрос лежит вне компетенции программы *git*. действуйте так, как-будто просто удалили файлы: резервная копия ведь вряд ли делалась, значит, последний шанс — файловая система ведь **могла** не перезаписать удалённые блоки, значит, можно попробовать воспользоваться этим последним шансом. ну а к программе *git* это уж точно не относится.

Comment: @Эникейщик, придумал, в каком случае может помочь команда fsck: если перед reset-ом изменённые файлы добавлялись в индекс/stash. в остальных случаях fsck в такой ситуации бесполезна.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут стэша очевидно не было :) К тому же оттуда можно же вроде и без танцев с fsck достать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вы правы, стэша не было.

Comment: если и в индексе не побывали (что тоже следует из вопроса), то … см. мой первый комментарий.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну, про stash правильнее было употребить слово «побывали» (т.е. stash был создан, а потом удалён). я слишком сильно сократил комментарий.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо, перепробовал все варианты, вытащить актуальные данные не удалось. Пришлось воспользоваться кэшэм памяти в голове.

Comment: Пиши с нуля. Всё пропало.